# How do I avoid duplicate Order ID

Tags: php, mysql, redundancy

I am facing a problem with possible duplicate order id, if submit at the same time.

May I know how to fully solve this problem or avoid it happened?

Below is my code showing how I am getting order ID and send it to database

```
<?php

                $sqlt = "SELECT ORD_ID FROM tpointgroup WHERE Group_ID = '$tid'";
                $order = mysqli_query($conn , $sqlt);
                $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($order);
                if ($rowcount == 0)
                    echo "No records found";        
                else 
                {
                    $rowt = mysqli_fetch_assoc($order);
                }
                $ordid = $rowt["ORD_ID"] + 1;
?>

 $ORD_ID = date('ym').str_pad($tkid, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

$insert = "insert into cusinfo (ORD_ID) values ('$ORD_ID')";
$insert3 = "UPDATE tpointgroup SET 
    ORD_ID = '$ordid' 
    WHERE Group_ID = $tid ";
```

I take order ID from tpointgroup table, because I want to know what is the current order ID and add 1 to it.
 When user click submit, the order ID will be assign to the customer and update the current orderID to the table tpointgroup.

But something is going wrong in my system with duplicate order id, if two or more users submit at the same time, the order id of customer will be same.

Comment: Use SELECT DISTINCT ORD_ID FROM tpointgroup WHERE Group_ID = '$tid'

Comment: which is the `PRIMARY-KEY` of `tpointgroup` table? is there any `AUTO-INCREMENT` field in `tpointgroup`

Comment: @mith ,yes it still have another auto increment inside the same table

Comment: MySql allows exactly one or zero auto increment column(s).

Comment: Execute `SHOW CREATE TABLE tpointgroup;` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE cusinfo;` in any MySql frontend and add the result to your question using the "edit" link below your question.

Comment: sorry for did not told early,my orderid can be same while different shop.Let say a customer order from shop A,the order id is12, but another customer order in shop B,the orderid can be 10 or another number

Comment: Then use a primary key on two columns, e.g. oderid, shopid.

Comment: Please add the table definitions to your question as described above (SHOW CREATE TABLE)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following to generate unique order id.

```
$order_id = time() . mt_rand() . $tid;
```

Comment: That is just a dirty workaround, not the way to go. It is preferable to have running order id numbers. Some tax authorities might want gapless order numbers.